# Rdlc reports: about subreports datasets

Tags: sql, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2008

I use visual studio 2010 with sql reporting services.
Do you know any good tutorial about subreports and how to pass datasets to subreports using rdlc files?

Comment: Not sure about a tutorial but it's easy to add datasets to subreports with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.subreportprocessing.aspx and using `e.DataSources`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good resource that helped me out with report issues:
http://www.gotreportviewer.com/

There's a page on common sub-report problems and how to fix them: http://www.gotreportviewer.com/subreports/index.html